# Questions about making hard kefir cheese

Tags: cheese, kefir

I am attempting to make hard kefir cheese in a cheese press.  Unfortunately the cheese press I purchased did not come with specific instructions.  I was able to find an article (http://www.culturesforhealth.com/hard-kefir-cheese-recipe/) but it is vague in certain respects.  Therefore I have two questions about the process.

How much PSI should be outputted onto the kefir to make hard cheese?

By the time the milk has been turned into kefir, it has already been sitting out for perhaps 24-48 hours.  Is it necessary to refrigerate the kefir while draining it and while pressing it into cheese, or can it sit at room temperature during this process?

Answer (score 2):

Welcome! According to  [this site](http://robincoe.hubpages.com/hub/How-to-Make-Kefir-Cheese) , you should refrigerate the kefir while draining and pressing. (See excerpt below.)

While I can't find a specific reference to an exact PSI for the draining and pressing  process, everything I read says to start with a plate on top and add more weight every few hours for the length of the process.

> Place the colander and bowl in the refrigerator for 48 hours to allow all of the whey to drain. Set a plate on top of your cheese and allow it to sit for a few hours. Continue to add more weight every few hours by putting another plate on top of your cheese to press out the remaining whey.